# How to call get method inside class with dynamic index in flutter?

Tags: flutter, localization, l10n.js

I adopt l10n into my project to support multilingual in my app.

The generated AppLocalizations classes contains multiple get method for the translated text.

I want to programmatically(or called dynamically) call these get method in my screen body, how can I do that?

***Generated Translate Dart***

```
import 'translate.dart';

/// The translations for English (`en`).
class AppLocalizationsEn extends AppLocalizations {
  AppLocalizationsEn([String locale = 'en']) : super(locale);

  @override
  String get splashPageViewTitle1 => 'Welcome!';

  @override
  String get splashPageViewTitle2 => 'Let's go';

  @override
  String get splashPageViewTitle3 => 'Byebye';
}
```

***Before Build***

```
List splashData = [
  {
    "textCode": "splashPageViewTitle1",
    "image": "assets/images/splash_1.png"
  },
  {
    "textCode": "splashPageViewTitle2",
    "image": "assets/images/splash_2.png"
  },
  {
    "textCode": "splashPageViewTitle3",
    "image": "assets/images/splash_3.png"
  },
];
```

***Inside Build***

```
Expanded(
  flex: 3,
  child: PageView.builder(
    onPageChanged: (value) {
      setState((){
        currentPage = value;
      });
    },
    itemCount: splashData.length,
    itemBuilder: (context, index) => SplashContent(
      image: splashData[index]["image"],
      //text: splashData[index]["text"]
      text: AppLocalizations.of(context)!.['splashPageViewTitle'+index] //<<<<<<<<<<<<<Failed in here!
    ),
  ),
),
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: The error showing: Error: Expected an identifier, but got '['.
Try inserting an identifier before '['.
                  text: AppLocalizations.of(context)!.['splashPageViewTitle'+index]

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to access the class instance is:

```
AppLocalizations.of(context)!.splashPageViewTitle1
```

But as you are trying to access depending on the index you can create a separate function:

```
String title(int index) {
  if(index == 1) {
    return AppLocalizations.of(context)!.splashPageViewTitle1;
   } else if(index == 2) {
     return AppLocalizations.of(context)!.splashPageViewTitle2;
      } else if(index == 3){
      return AppLocalizations.of(context)!.splashPageViewTitle3;
     }
 }
```

And use it on your `itemBuilder` like this:

```
itemBuilder: (context, index) => SplashContent(
      image: splashData[index]["image"],
      //text: splashData[index]["text"]
      text: title(index),     //// <----- here 
    ),
```

Comment: Thank, but is there any way to access dynamically according to index given? like
obj['key'+index] in javascript? Your solution given might cause a very long if/else condition checking once the translate list grows up.

Comment: Yes, that's the only problem with this solution, I think that would be better to create a list of titles, this way it would easy to access like titlesList[index].